# How to use \contournumber with contour package

Tags: graphics, text

I'm trying to get more white halo around text. I'm using `tikz` and `contour` package. I know that I should use `\contournumber{X}` to change the numbers of copies. But I can't figure out how to use the command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, draw=black] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (0, 0) node[]     {\contour{white} {I CAN FEEL YOUR HALO HALO HALO!!}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

%   \contournumber{64}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of copies does not make the white halo larger, but smoother. The larger white area can be achieved by increasing the contour length. The following example sets both:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contournumber{64}% default is 16, star form uses 32
\contourlength{.06em}% default is 0.03em

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, draw=black] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (0, 0) node[] {\contour{white} {I CAN FEEL YOUR HALO HALO HALO!!}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result contour]

Implementation via package `pdfrender` that uses a PDF feature for vector fonts.
Therefore, it is limited to PDF mode of pdfTeX and LuaTeX (recent LuaTeX also
requires package `luatex85`). The advantage is that the text is drawn twice only. The first time it is stroked with a thick line width in white, then it is
overprinted in black.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\newcommand*{\contour}[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{%
    \textpdfrender{
      TextRenderingMode=Stroke,
      StrokeColor=white,
      LineWidth=.12em,
    }{#2}%
  }%
  \mbox{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, draw=black] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw (0, 0) node[] {\contour{white} {I CAN FEEL YOUR HALO HALO HALO!!}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result pdfrender]

The width of the white halo in comparison: 2 * `contour` length = 1 * line width of `pdfrender`.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't think of putting the command in the pre-maple. I was trying to put with the sentence.  - Great, I like the pdf render method. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Heiko, would you mind to print the link to this answer into the manual of pdfrender.sty? Because from reading the manual I didn't get any idea what the whole package was good for.

Comment: After several days diagnosing various `\contour` issues as part of my conversion from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`, I found this little gem of a comment regarding how "`recent LuaTeX also requires package luatex85`". As the `\contour` documentation makes no mention of the `luatex85` requirement when using `lualatex` that I could see (and no mention of `luatex` or `lualatex` either), perhaps an update to the 2004/11/18 `\contour` documentation is in order.